# what is the proper HTTP status code for a failed login request? (or why do gmail/fb respond with a new page)

Tags: facebook, http, gmail, http-status-codes

I was looking for the proper HTTP status code for a login request, and I haven't found anything to indicate there is one.

Then, I noticed that GMail and Facebook respond with new pages on a failure.

I have two questions:
-Is there a proper HTTP status code for a failed login?
-Is there a security reason that both Google and FB respond with a new webpage instead of an error of some kind?

Comment: What login requests? When you go to Facebook.com?

Comment: If the user input the wrong credentials, they need to be notified of that, and given a chance to try again. _How else_ would that possibly work, if not by serving them what you call a “new page”? // Yes, they could probably deliver that page with a status code like 403 Forbidden or something else that might be appropriate. […]

Comment: […] But the potential drawbacks (f.e. some browsers might not display the HTML code returned, when the status indicates an error) would outweigh the possible benefits (of which there actually aren’t any in this case, I’d say - the login flow is supposed to be used by actual human users only, and not any bots or clients for which a “correct” HTTP response code might be important.)

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP based authentication methods the IETF spec is below:

"A 401 (Unauthorized) response message is used by an origin server to
challenge the authorization of a user agent, including a
WWW-Authenticate header field containing at least one challenge
applicable to the requested resource."  [IETF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235)

Google and Facebook are likely using something like OpenAuth, not standard HTTP authentication.  [OpenAuth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#page-8) uses redirection based authentication.  And Forms based authentication is implemented by the application technology being employed and could involve a redirect.

So in short, for pure HTTP authentication (basic, digest) the server should return a 401 or 407.  But for other types of authentication mechanisms, a redirect may be employed.

Please explore the links I included, they will provide you with much more in depth information.